# Bootstrap 5 [beta] no longer has jQuery - hamburger doesn't open/collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Did some first ever bootstrap experimentation with v4.6 and hamburger worked as expected in that shrinking screen size resulted in hamburger appearing and would open and collapse.

Thought would try with the v5 beta and noticed two immediate changes in the beta:

- jQuery is removed
- ml-auto now ms-auto

However in testing v5, while the hamburger will appear, it does not open/collapse as expected.
Is there some other change between Bootstrap v4 and v5 that I've missed?
Or some unknown Vanilla JS that should replace some jQuery that enables the hamburger functionality?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous" -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div class="container-fluid">
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm" style="background-color: #039;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="/img/test.png" class="d-inline-block align-middle" alt="image brand"> Image brand
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto"><!-- in bootstrap 4 it is ml-auto -->
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12"><hr style="margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px; " /></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">1st col</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">2nd col</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">3rd col</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-sm-12 small"></div>
  </div>

  
</div>
    <!-- script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script -->\
    <!-- script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check their [Get Started Page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/)? or their [Migration Page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/)

Answer (score 1):

aha:

data-bs-toggle
data-bs-target